# Java - Algorithm - Display all the possibilities of sequence

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, combinations, sequence

Please help me to find the most efficient solution for below.

```
int max = 2;
int sequenceLength = 3;
List<Integer> sequence = new ArrayList<Integer>(sequenceLength);
List<List<Integer>> possibilitites = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
...solution...
System.out.print(possibilitites);
```

sequenceLength is the length of each sequence.

Sequence will contain combination of number, between 0 to Max, which is 2.

Each sequence created, will be added to possibilities.

The solution should be able to handle any max and sequenceLength.

Expected result:

(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,0,2),(0,1,0),(0,1,1), and so on

Comment: There are `(max+1) ^ length` possibilities, so 27 for `max=2` and `length=3`. That number gets really big as `length` increases. For example, if `max=1` and `length=32` there are 4 billion possibilities.

Comment: thank you for the formula, it helps. but I need the possibilities ArrayList too.

Comment: There may be a built-in function in Java that I'm not aware of. But generating the possibilities can be done with a simple counting algorithm. E.g. with `max=2` and `length=3` there are 27 possibilities, so use a loop to count from 0 to 26, and then break the number down into digits base 3. You can also count using an array of digits. Increment the least significant digit. If the result is greater than `max` set the digit to 0, and increment the next digit. You're done when the most-significant digit reaches `max+1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain loop-based implementation of the sequence generator as suggested by @user3386109 in the comments:

```
    static List<List<Integer>> generate(final int max, final int len) {
        final int limit = max + 1;
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0, n = (int) Math.pow(limit, len); i < n; i++) {
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
            
            int num = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                
                list.add(0, num % limit);
                num /= limit;
            }
            result.add(list);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Other option is to use `String.format` and conversion to Integer with specific radix (`max + 1`):

```
static List<List<Integer>> generate2(final int max, final int len) {
        final int limit = max + 1;
        return IntStream
                .range(0, (int)Math.pow(limit, len))
                .mapToObj(i -> 
                    String.format("%" + len + "s", Integer.toString(i, limit))
                          .replace(' ', '0')
                          .chars()
                            .map(c -> c - '0')
                            .boxed()
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())
                )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
                
    }
```

Comment: I tried the 1st solution, it works, thank you